# How to set a default user on the login screen without automatically logging in?

Tags: user-account, login-screen

I have more than one user account on my MacBook, but I'm almost always the one logging in. I don't want to have a click an icon or type my username. I do however, want my account to always be password protected. Basically, I want my account to be selected by default so all I have to do after turning on my computer is type in my password. If someone else needs to log in, they would press the back button,

Comment: I don't think this is possible, @Zorgoth. (Great handle, BTW.)

Answer (score 4):

You can activate the "require password" option in system preferences:

### [image]

Whenever you are done working you can then just close your MacBook or set it to sleep (instead of logging out or shutting it down, which I assume is what you normally do). If you open it up again after the specified time you are prompted to enter your password, but you are still able to switch user.

<s>Achieving this behaviour after a complete shutdown however is not possible, i believe.</s>

**EDIT:** *Maybe* there is a way to achieve this after all, since that is precisely what happens after the installation of a macOS update (that required reboot) is finished. Maybe a specific boot flag that can be set or some config in a plist file...

Comment: This is really bizarre. I have the same request - I don't want to have to select my account every time I reboot, but I also do want to require a password. Your solution definitely works for waking, but really strange that to defeat it all you have to do is power cycle the computer! This seems like a really basic function. Yet I'm on 11.6.8 and don't see a way to do it.